# How many Sprite Atlases should be used?

Tags: unity, sprites

I am using Sprite Atlases in my game to fix a bug with gaps between tiles as a result of oversampling, and I started wondering how the atlases should be used.

What I'm asking here is whether I should use one atlas for all of the sprites, use multiple atlases as categories of some sort, or only use them with images with multiple sprites (to fix the bug).

Comment: The wording suggests that this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/228147). Is the real issue is you want to see if there's a better solution for the oversampling bug? Or is the oversampling bug extraneous info & the real issue is when to consider multiple atlas?

Comment: My issue is the latter, as said in the second paragraph. The bug is easily fixable, even without the atlases, however I think they are the most convenient method.